# Formation of vortices in superconductors

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, superconductivity, surface-tension, vortex

So I'm trying to understand how mixed state of a type II superconductor becomes the energetically favourable state.

I've been through a simple approximate calculation considering a S-N boundary to see that the surface energy at the interface is $\sigma = \frac{B^2}{2\mu_0}(\xi - \lambda)$, so I understand that type II superconductors have $\kappa = \lambda / \xi \gg 1$ and hence negative surface energy.

Since they have negative surface energy then they should want to create as many S-N boundaries as possible right? I get that cylinders are the most efficient way to do this, but what other energy is at play that limits it and stops it from creating an infinite amount of boundaries?

Any help is appreciated (conceptual or mathematical)

Thanks :)

Comment: Vortices repel each other, that's what stabilise the lattice. They can also be pinned on defects, mostly lattice defects. The book by deGennes is a good introduction to the physics of vortex in superconductors.